Subnet cannot view server ip (OPENVPN)
I have an OPENVPN server set up on Ubuntu Server.
I assigned a different subnet to 2 particular clients using the ccd function.
Being on said subnet both see each other without problems.
The drawback is that when they are connected they lose their internet connection since they do not see the IP of the open vpn server.
PS: If the client obtains the subnet from the openvpn server, he has an internet connection without problems.
I share my server.conf / iptables file
Server IP range: 10.8.0.0
Subnet IP range: 10.9.0.0
server.conf
local **MY YP**
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key
dh dh.pem
auth SHA512
tls-crypt tc.key
topology subnet
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
client-config-dir ccd
route 10.9.0.0 255.255.255.0
client-to-client
management 127.0.0.1 5555
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
push "block-outside-dns"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"
keepalive 10 120
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
verb 3
crl-verify crl.pem
explicit-exit-notify

iptables
[Unit]
Before=network.target
[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 ! -d 10.8.0.0/24 -j SNAT --to MY IP
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/iptables -I INPUT -p udp --dport 1194 -j ACCEPT
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/iptables -I FORWARD -s 10.8.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/iptables -I FORWARD -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
ExecStop=/usr/sbin/iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 ! -d 10.8.0.0/24 -j SNAT --to MY IP
ExecStop=/usr/sbin/iptables -D INPUT -p udp --dport 1194 -j ACCEPT
ExecStop=/usr/sbin/iptables -D FORWARD -s 10.8.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT
ExecStop=/usr/sbin/iptables -D FORWARD -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

RemainAfterExit=yes
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

client1 file
ifconfig-push 10.9.0.5 255.255.0.0

client2 file
ifconfig-push 10.9.0.6 255.255.0.0

Is there a way for clients on the subnet to see the server's IP so they can have a connection?
Thanks you.

I'm not entirely clear what the problem is here. What does "see" mean (as in "Is there a way for clients on the subnet to see the server's IP so they can have a connection?")? It would be helpful to see the output of ip route on each server both before and after starting openvpn.

Hello, sorry but my English is not very good.
When I say "see" I mean that if I make a ping from network 10.9.0.0 to 10.8.0.0, no packet responds.
Is there a possibility that there could be traffic between both networks?

I would suggest that you take a look at chatgpt, and post your question into it in your native language and tell it translate it into English. it is currently not very clear what you want to solve with this.

You do push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp" which tells the OpenVPN clients to redirect all traffic over the VPN.

Hello vidarlo, I already have that push in my code in the server.conf file. That should make ALL IP ranges (including those that I configure for each client through ccd) allow them to have an internet connection once they connect?
